# JQuery is not working after complete load of the page

Tags: jquery

Hi i have a strange problem with wordpress. I have a short JQuery script. The script is working as long as the page is loading. But when the page is finished with loading it's not working anymore and I can't find the prolbem. I tried also to  wrap the script in a noconflict wrapper didn't help.

Maybe some more informations... I try to show a title of a grid element in wordpress which i have set to display none.

Thanks for your help

Here some details:
Wordpress 5.3.2
Highend Theme 3.6.4

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery(".apmstoriespic").mouseover(function(){
    jQuery(this).next(".apmstoriestitle").show();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say what the problem is without seeing the html structure. Any error in your browser console log ? Might that another jQuery function is already bind to the ".apmstoriespic" class. Maybe try the below instead

```
jQuery(".apmstoriespic").on('hover',function(){
```

If you want to skip the jQuery route altogether, there is an easy way to achieve the same result with CSS only

```
.apmstoriespic + .apmstoriestitle {
    display: none;
 }

.apmstoriespic:hover + .apmstoriestitle {
    display: block;
 }
```

Hope this help !

Comment: Thx for the css Tipp

Comment: @MartinKörber Did that do the job ? If that worked don't hesitate to accept my answer :)